# TableView empties when interacting

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

So I have 2 Views that are shown inside a UIView, based on what is selected on the SegmentViewController. I create dummy data, returning 20 row of a custom cell. This works great.

Everything is fine, till I interact with the TableView.

[image: Content is gone]

Bellow is my code:

**GoalsViewController.swift**

```swift
import UIKit

class GoalsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var goalsTableView: UITableView!
    let goalCellIdentifier = "goalCell"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        goalsTableView.delegate = self
        goalsTableView.dataSource = self

        goalsTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "GoalsViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: goalCellIdentifier)

        goalsTableView.reloadData()
    }


}

extension GoalsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = goalsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: goalCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! GoalsViewCell
        cell.goalTitle.text = "aaaaa"
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Selected \(indexPath.row)")
    }

   }
```

After any of the empty rows is selected, the `didSelectRowAt` is not called, so the cells are not there at all. I tried to find a solution, but I was only to find issues about empty lists, before being populated.

What could be the reason for the empty tableview?

Comment: Are you calling `reloadData` anywhere else?

Comment: It looks like your contained views aren't constrained correctly and so as soon as there is an autolayout pass they are being resized or moved offscreen. Do you get constraint warnings in the console? Why does "debug view hierarchy" show?  Try a trial of "reveal". It is a great tool

Comment: @dfd No, I don't call it somewhere else. Not even on the main ViewController.
@Paulw11 That's a wonderful tool. Thanks for your suggestion, no idea! So, I changed the text name to `indexPath.row` to know which row is which.When the list is full, I can see with white colour the items that are visible. After I click everything turns gray, but the values are still there.Here is a screenshot https://i.imgur.com/OjDYjqY.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will explain what was the issue for people who probably did not know (like me).
So my `UITableView` is inside a `UIView` that changes based on what the user is selecting. In total I had 2 different Views that where switching. The reason that it was emptying it was because my parent ViewController, could not access the delegate for UITableView. To fix that, after adding a subview to the UIView, you need also to move the ViewController to the parent controller. In code it goes like this.

```swift
// Empty array of UIViewControllers
var views: [UIViewController]!

// Add the UIViewControllers to the array
views = [UIViewController()]
views.append(EventsViewController())
views.append(GoalsViewController())

for view in views {
      // Needed to adjust the size of Subview to size of View
      view.view.frame = containerView.bounds
      // Add the subviews
      containerView.addSubview(view.view)
}

// Bring the view in position 1 to the front of the UIView
containerView.bringSubviewToFront(views[1].view)
// Add Views[1] UIViewController as a child to the parent controller
self.addChild(views[1])
views[1].didMove(toParent: self)

// After done with everything with the UIViewController remove it
views[1].removeFromParent()
```

- [addChild Apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621394-addchild)
- [didMove Apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621405-didmove)

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong here but one thing that I've noticed is that you are not implementing a function which sets the height of each cell.

```
// Specify the height of your cells
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return 100 // Or your given cell height.
}
```

So here is my theory: If you are using constraints something is missing and your cell's height can't be identified by constraints alone or you are not using constraints at all thus you must use [heightForRowAt](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview) function to specify each cell's height.

Comment: Unluckily it didn't help. I also tried to set it directly on the viewDidLoad function by setting the rowHeight attribute on the table. The size changes to the one i set but it is empty once again.